# yii2 Dynamically call widget

Tags: yii2

I have an action in a controller and it must works like a "factory widget":

```
public function actionRenderWidget($widget)
{
    $widgetClass = 'My'.$widget.'Widget';
    return $widgetClass::widget();
}
```

What is the correct way to implement something similar?

Answer (score 3):

You should simply use class name with namespace (no need to use `call_user_func()`), e.g. :

```
$widgetClass = 'app\widgets\My'.$widget.'Widget';
return $widgetClass::widget();
```

Read more about [Dynamically accessing namespaced elements](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.dynamic.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
//example
$className = 'yii\jui\DatePicker';

return call_user_func($className .'::widget');
```

OR

```
$config = [];
$widget = Yii::createObject($className, $config);
return call_user_func([$widget, 'widget']);
```